# VBA: How do I include hyperlinks when transferring data to multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a data organization system. I have created a sub that will import a spreadsheet full of data (sheet1), allow the user to categorize each entry to a specific department (Column L), and then distribute the data to a master spreadsheet (Cumlative-bydirectorate), and to the respective sub sheet based on the department categorization (Column L).

I'm having trouble keeping the hyperlinks present in column A when transferring to the various sheets. I'm not sure what to change to keep the hyperlinks in the transferred cells.

here is the code I'm using. It is only pasting the cell values, not the hyperlink embedded within the cell. Column A consists of numbers, but each number is associated with a unique hyperlink

```
Sub copyrows()

Dim wsMst As Worksheet
Dim wsDpt As Worksheet
Dim wsImp As Worksheet
Dim lSRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lMRow As Long
Dim lDRow As Long

Set wsImp = Sheets("sheet1")
Set wsMst = Sheets("Cumulative-bydirectorate")

lSRow = 2

lMRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsMst.Range("$A:$A")) + 1

Do Until wsImp.Cells(lSRow, 1) = ""

    Set wsDpt = Sheets(wsImp.Range("L" & lSRow).Value2)
    lDRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsDpt.Range("$A:$A")) + 1

    For lCol = 1 To 12

        wsMst.Cells(lMRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)
        wsDpt.Cells(lDRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)

    Next lCol

    wsImp.Rows(lSRow).ClearContents

    lMRow = lMRow + 1
    lSRow = lSRow + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the first cell (column A): **[Not Tested]**

```vb
Sub copyrows()

Dim wsMst As Worksheet
Dim wsDpt As Worksheet
Dim wsImp As Worksheet
Dim lSRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lMRow As Long
Dim lDRow As Long

Set wsImp = Sheets("sheet1")
Set wsMst = Sheets("Cumulative-bydirectorate")

lSRow = 2

lMRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsMst.Range("$A:$A")) + 1

Do Until wsImp.Cells(lSRow, 1) = ""

    Set wsDpt = Sheets(wsImp.Range("L" & lSRow).Value2)
    lDRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsDpt.Range("$A:$A")) + 1

    wsImp.Cells(lSRow, 1).Copy Destination:=wsMst.Cells(lMRow, 1)
    wsImp.Cells(lSRow, 1).Copy Destination:=wsDpt.Cells(lDRow, 1)

    For lCol = 2 To 12

        wsMst.Cells(lMRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)
        wsDpt.Cells(lDRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)

    Next lCol    

    wsImp.Rows(lSRow).ClearContents

    lMRow = lMRow + 1
    lSRow = lSRow + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: That helped copy the hyperlinks to the master spreadsheet, but not the sub sheets. The entries pasted in the sub sheets with column A empty.

Comment: Where in the code provided are you transferring data to sub sheets?

Comment: `Do Until wsImp.Cells(lSRow, 1) = ""

    Set wsDpt = Sheets(wsImp.Range("L" & lSRow).Value2)
    lDRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsDpt.Range("$A:$A")) + 1

    For lCol = 1 To 12

        wsMst.Cells(lMRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)
        wsDpt.Cells(lDRow, lCol) = wsImp.Cells(lSRow, lCol)

    Next lCol`

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with comment formatting. Immediately following the "do until" loop, wsDpt is whichever cell value is present in that entry under column L. Then the program manually writes in the info present from import sheet to the destination sheet

Comment: Apologies, I missed the second line in the inner loop. Updated.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!